# Php multi level inheritance best practice

Tags: php, oop, architecture

During some workaround with some architecture I faced a question and I am wondering if this implementation follows best practice or not.

Here we have a base abstract class:

```
abstract class A {

    protected mixed $object;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->loadObject()
             ->fuc1();
    }

    abstract protected function loadObject(): self;
    abstract public function fuc1(): bool;
    abstract public function fuc3(): iterable;
}
```

In this case, I want to implement Class B and C. if I create each class separately everything is fine but as far as these 2 classes have the same functions I decided to create a base class for them (`BC`) so codes are now like this:

```
class BC extends A {

    protected string x;
    protected string y;

    protected function loadObject(): self {
         throw new \Exception('Child must implement loeadObject');
    }
    public function fuc1(): bool {
         //Some Codes
    }
    public function fuc3(): iterable {
        //Some Codes
    }
    
}
```

And Class B and Class C are like this:

```
class B extends BC {

    protected function loadObject(): self {
        $this->object = new SomeObject();
        return $this;
    }
}

class C extends BC {

    protected function loadObject(): self {
        $this->object = new SomeObject2();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

We also can not move `loadObject` function to class BC cuz maybe class D wants to inherit directly from class A.

We can also rely on interfaces but I was wondering if some one forget to make class B/C implement an Interface then we will have problem in class A.

So is it a good practice that we throw exceptions in the class BC and force other developers to don't forget to overwrite the `loadObject` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good practice, if you doesn't need to implement the `loadObject` method in the `BC` class, you should keep it abstract.

```
abstract class BC extends A {
    protected string $x;
    protected string $y;

    public function fuc1(): bool {
    }
    public function fuc3(): iterable {
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I fixed my typo. but class `BC` should implement `loadObject()` function

Comment: Why `BC` have to implement it?

Comment: Cuz `BC` extends `A` and `loadObject()` is marked as `abstract` in `A`. if not we get this error:
`Fatal error: Class BC contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (A::loadObject)`
see here https://onlinephp.io/c/34a52

Comment: So I mentioned class `BC` also need to be abstract, or is there any reason you can't mark it as abstract?

Comment: Oh, you are right I thought I make the BC to be abstract. Thanks